# SQL group by of a group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-ce

Let's say I have 3 tables: customers, weapons and orders. What I want is to create a table where for each customer I need to display quantity of goods he/she bought per category(gun, pistol, etc.) and total quantity of weapons? Is it implementable using just SQL query? Can I implement this without subquery because I intend to use SQL CE?

Tables has following structure:
customers(id, name)
weapons(id, weapon_type)
orders(cust_id, weap_id, quantity)

And I want to get this:

```
Name       | Order(w_type) |    Quantity  |   Total
-----------+---------------+--------------+-----------
John Smith |   Guns        |     3        |   7
John Smith |   Pistols     |     4        |   7
-----------+---------------+--------------+-----------
Jane Doe   |   Guns        |     5        |   14
Jane Doe   |   Pistols     |     7        |   14
Jane Doe   |   Cannons     |     2        |   14
```

or (even better)

```
Name       |   Order       |    Quantity  |   Total
-----------+---------------+--------------+-----------
John Smith |   Guns        |     3        |   
John Smith |   Pistols     |     4        |   
-----------+---------------+--------------+-----------                                         
                                              7   
-----------+---------------+--------------+-----------
Jane Doe   |   Guns        |     5        |   
Jane Doe   |   Pistols     |     7        |   
Jane Doe   |   Cannons     |     2        |   
-----------+---------------+--------------+-----------
                                              14
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your existing query? And maybe the full table structures so we can see how they are linked to each other?
A `group-by` clause allows you to specify more than one column, so you can have `group by name, w_type, etc`. Also, having the total as a separate record *might* be possible in some SQL dialects (I think Oracle can do it with `roll-up`), but I'm not sure about SQL CE.

Comment: I use:
select c.name, w.type, sum(o.q) quantity from orders o join cust c on o.cust_id = c.id join weapons w on w.id = o.weap_id
group by c.name, w.type

Answer (score 0):

There is no analytical function (e.g. SUM() OVER ) in CE that can give you the first result.

If your intended ("even better") results is the 2nd, which isn't even tabular, you need to fire two queries; one for the table and one for the sum.  Either that, or collect the sum as you are going through the table result (ordered by person).